# Decrypting RSA data encrypted in python with cryptodome in C# using bouncycastle gives error block incorrect

Tags: c#, python, encryption, rsa, bouncycastle

I am using the following function to encrypt RSA data in PHP:

```
    function RSAEncrypt($text){
    $priv_key=file_get_contents("privateKey.key");
    //$passphrase is required if your key is encoded (suggested)
    $priv_key_res = openssl_get_privatekey($priv_key);



    if(!openssl_private_encrypt($text,$crypttext,$priv_key_res)){
        echo "Error: " . openssl_error_string ();
    }
    return $crypttext;

}
```

I am decoding this in C# with the following function:

```
public static string RSADecrypt(string b64cipher, string pemcert) {
    byte[] bytesCypherText = Convert.FromBase64String(b64cipher);

    Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509Certificate cert = (Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509Certificate)new Org.BouncyCastle.OpenSsl.PemReader(new StringReader(pemcert)).ReadObject();
    var decryptEngine = new Pkcs1Encoding(new RsaEngine());
    //var decryptEngine = new OaepEncoding(new RsaEngine());

    decryptEngine.Init(false, cert.GetPublicKey());

    string decrypted = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decryptEngine.ProcessBlock(bytesCypherText, 0, bytesCypherText.Length));
    return decrypted;
}
```

I want to replace the PHP function with python, and tried the following:

```
from Cryptodome.PublicKey import RSA
from Cryptodome.Cipher import PKCS1_OAEP, AES, PKCS1_v1_5
import base64
from Cryptodome import Random
from Cryptodome.Random import get_random_bytes
import hashlib
def encrypt_private_key(a_message):
    with open("privateKey.key", 'r') as f:
        private_key = RSA.importKey(f.read())
    #encryptor = PKCS1_OAEP.new(private_key)
    encryptor= PKCS1_v1_5.new(private_key)
    encrypted_msg = encryptor.encrypt(a_message.encode())
    encoded_encrypted_msg = base64.b64encode(encrypted_msg)
    return encoded_encrypted_msg
```

However, when decoding I get the following error:

```
InvalidCipherTextException: block incorrect

at byte[] Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Encodings.Pkcs1Encoding.DecodeBlock
 (byte[] input, int inOff, int inLen) at string RSADecrypt (string
 b64cipher, string pemcert)
```

If I try to use PKCS1_OAEP (in python and c#, see commented code), I am getting a data wrong exception.

Not sure what am I missing

Comment: I was referring to:
//var decryptEngine = new OaepEncoding(new RsaEngine());
and
#encryptor = PKCS1_OAEP.new(private_key)
in C# and python snipper respectively

Comment: In RSA, encryption is done with the public key and decryption is done with the private key. You seem to be trying to do the opposite. However, pycryptodome just ignores you and uses the public key instead.

Comment: They key file only contains a PEM encoded privatekey file, pycryptodome does not have access to corresponding public key

Comment: As a workaround, this seems to work: https://www.php2python.com/wiki/function.openssl-private-encrypt/

Comment: The privatekey file includes the public key.

Comment: If you think you want private key encryption then you probably want signing. In that case you should use the sign/verify APIs which take care of some important things for you. There are very few cases where you actually want to "encrypt" with the private key.

Comment: My use case is to make a license system. The license content is XML that is encrypted using AES. The Key and IV are RSA Encrypted. it makes more sense to me to have the certificate corresponding to the PVK bundled in the software that will read the license rather than the PVK that should be kept on the license issuing system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research, it seems python lirary does not allow to make private key encryption as it is not a standard operation, however in my case I still wanted to do it, and used the code here:
https://www.php2python.com/wiki/function.openssl-private-encrypt/

```
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.ciphers import Cipher, algorithms, modes

from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.serialization import load_pem_private_key
def openssl_private_encrypt(data):
    """Encrypt data with RSA private key.
    This is a rewrite of the function from PHP, using cryptography
    FFI bindings to the OpenSSL library. Private key encryption is
    non-standard operation and Python packages either don't offer
    it at all, or it's incompatible with the PHP version.
    The backend argument MUST be the OpenSSL cryptography backend.
    """
    # usage
    key = load_pem_private_key(open("key.pem").read().encode(
        'ascii'), None, backend=default_backend())
    backend = default_backend()
    length = backend._lib.EVP_PKEY_size(key._evp_pkey)
    buffer = backend._ffi.new('unsigned char[]', length)
    result = backend._lib.RSA_private_encrypt(
        len(data), data, buffer,
        backend._lib.EVP_PKEY_get1_RSA(key._evp_pkey),
        backend._lib.RSA_PKCS1_PADDING)
    backend.openssl_assert(result == length)
    res = backend._ffi.buffer(buffer)[:]
    print(res)
    return base64.b64encode(backend._ffi.buffer(buffer)[:]).decode()
```